# Php code printing multiple lines when converted notation to integer

Tags: php, api

I am trying to get the 'LastPrice' and 'Label' from the cryptopia api. I get it right but the Lastprice displayed is shown as notation 1.124E-5
When i use number_format($price, 8) , the output displays multiple lines of the price with one having the price and others having all zeros like:

> 0.00000000
>   0.00000000
>   XVI/LTC
>   0.00001124
>   0.00000000

but it should be like

> XVI/LTC
>   0.00001124

```
<?php

    // construct the query with our apikey and the query we want to make
    $endpoint = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarket/2422';
    // setup curl to make a call to the endpoint
    $session = curl_init($endpoint);
    // indicates that we want the response back
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // exec curl and get the data back
    $data = curl_exec($session);
    // remember to close the curl session once we are finished retrieveing the data
    curl_close($session);
    // decode the json data to make it easier to parse the php
    $search_results = json_decode($data, true);
    if ($search_results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');
    //print_r($search_results);
    echo '<table>';

    foreach ($search_results as $coin) {

    $name = $coin["Label"];
    $price = $coin["LastPrice"];


    echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>' . number_format($price, 8) . '</td></tr>';
    }
        echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

Need your help

Comment: Can you `var_dump($coin)` for each iteration please?

Comment: no it doesnt work sadly